# How to swap the last name and first name without a comma with vim

Tags: vim

I have a long list of name in order of `Family name, First name`. I'd like to change this to `First name Last name` with vim.

What is the best way. Thank you for your help.

```
Berclaz, Lucy
Carlow, Rese
Chang, Karen
DiCanilo, Sophy
Hisaeda, Kai
...
...
```

to

```
Lucy Berclaz
Rese Carlow
Karen Chang
Sophy DiCanilo
Kai Hisaeda
```

Comment: What have you tried? Capturing and re-ordering is covered by most regular expression tutorials!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.

```
%s/^\(\a\+\), \(\a\+\)/\2 \1/
```

See

```
:help /\(
:help /\a
:help /\+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below awk command works.

```
   awk -F"," '{print $2,$1;}' {filename} > {new-filename}
```